# matplotlib will only show the last plot (cannot superimpose plots)

Tags: python, matplotlib

My code uses several plt.plot() instructions to superimpose curves, and used to work perfectly until today. Now it looks like the last plt.plot() will delete the previous ones, so that I can't superimpose them.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
X = [i for i in range(5)]
plt.plot(X,[0]*5)
plt.plot(X,[1]*5)
plt.show()
```

Instead of getting two lines, which I did until now, it will only show the last one. I don't understand why that would happen, especially since I don't remember updating libraries. Do you know why it happens ?
Thanks

Comment: Is this your actual code? My first guess would be you are drawing the second curve over the first, but the example given doesn't do that. Please post an image of what you see if you run the code above.

Comment: The code above only shows the second curve, there is a line at y=1, and nothing at y=0.

Comment: I ran your code and I got a line at `y=0` and a line at `y=1`...

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
plt.plot(X, [0]*5, 'r--', X, [1]*5, 'g^')
plt.show()
```

Comment: This doesn't explain, what OP sees, though

Comment: It works for this simple case, but I need to do it using a loop, so it's not a solution for me. Thanks though

Answer (score 0):

Your code worked with my version of python and matplotlib, so I can't guarantee that this alternative solution will work for you, but you could try creating a figure and then adding plots to it like so:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
X = list(range(5))
for y in range(2):
    plt.plot(X, [y]*5)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Nothing changed